# Polymer data binding from Web API

Tags: html, data-binding, polymer, polymer-1.0

I want to bind some data to a variable on command (by the press of a button) from a server. On the server I have a function that will return a JSON object (this has been tested, if I open the API link directly, I do get the proper JSON format). However, the variable stays undefined, no matter what I do. I have a button and a table (`px-data-table` is part of a framework and should be able to display JSON formatted data):

```
<button id="runPredictionButton">
    <i>Button text</i>
</button>
<px-data-table 
      table-data$="{{data}}"
</px-data-table>
<div class="output"></div>
```

And I'm handling the button press and define the variables as follows:

```
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'custom-view',
      properties: {
        data: {
          type: Object,
          notify: true
        }
      },
    ready: function() {
      var self = this;
      this.$.runPredictionButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
          filerootdiv.querySelector('.output').innerHTML = 'Is here';    
          var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          this.data = xhr.open("GET", "API/predict") //as mentioned, API/predict returns a valid JSON
          console.log("This data is:" + this.data);
          this.data = xhr1.send("API/predict","_self")
          console.log("This data is_:" + this.data);
      });
    }
  });      
  </script>
```

For some reason, on the console `this.data` shows up as `undefined` both times I'm trying to print it. What am I missing? How to pass the JSON from the API call to the `this.data` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xhr.send()` doesn't return what you want.

You need to learn XmlHttpRequest first. Here is [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest). And some easy [examples](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp)

Simply, you need to listen to `onreadystatechange` on your `xml` variable. There you will be able to get data from server.

Additionaly, why are you using addEventListener. You can simply set `on-click`.

```
<button id="runPredictionButton" on-click="getDataFromServer">
    <i>Button text</i>
</button>
```

and then you can define javascript function which is called everytime user clicks on button.

```
getDataFromServer: function() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", "API/predict");
  xhr.send("API/predict","_self");
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
   // 4 = data returned
   if(xhr.readyState == 4) {
     // 200 = OK
     if (this.xhttp.status == 200) {
       // get data
       this.data = xhr.responseText;
     }
   }
  }.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Do you by any chance know how to do dynamic binding in Polymer 1? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50815342/polymer-data-change-doesnt-reflect